# KVM instance creation fails with 'virtio-net has no peer'

Tags: windows, kvm-virtualization, cloud, image

When I create a Windows Server 2008 instance for KVM with this command:

> kvm -m 2048 -cdrom win2008.iso -drive file=windowserver.img,if=virtio
>   -boot d -drive file=.virtio-win-0.1-22.iso,index=3,media=cdrom  -device virtio-net-pci -net nic -net user -nographic -vnc :5

The command returns with the following error:

> Warning: nic virtio-net-pci.0 has no peer

How do I fix this?

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning. What's the actual problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you want the `-device` parameter. If you want to use the virtio NIC, add the `model` option to the `-net` parameter like this:

```
-net nic,model=virtio
```

Your entire command would look like this then:

```
kvm -m 2048 -cdrom win2008.iso -drive file=windowserver.img,if=virtio -boot d -drive file=.virtio-win-0.1-22.iso,index=3,media=cdrom -net nic,model=virtio -net user -nographic -vnc :5
```